# Does npm publish perform an npm pack

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

Considering the **Node.js** package manager, namely **npm** - I was curious if the *publish* command performs the *pack* command prior to the publish or if it does something different altogether? So if I were to execute:

```
npm publish <folder>
```

Does it first perform the following:

```
npm pack <folder>
```

I was unable to find anything mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish).

---

The primary reason I'm curious about this is that our build process is simply doing the `npm publish` without the explicit `npm pack` prior, but the package doesn't appear to have the expected contents. i.e.; the contents of the `.tgz` differ when I perform a local `npm pack` to that of the contents of the `npm publish`.

Comment: what kind of difference you have?

Answer (score 3):

Having a look at the NPM source you can see that it arrives in the publishFromDirectory function, and calls into the pack module.

https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/b80d650def417645d2525863e9f17af57a917b42/lib/publish.js#L79 and again at
https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/b80d650def417645d2525863e9f17af57a917b42/lib/publish.js#L88

If you follow through into the pack module, you can see that the `_pack` function performs the same 2 steps:

https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/114d518c75732c42acbef3acab36ba1d0fd724e2/lib/pack.js#L67

So, to answer your question, it doesn't do exactly `pack <folder>` but does call into the same major code paths.

The code there is mostly well written and not difficult to follow, I would encourage you to dig into the source code of these projects for this type of question as your knowledge on the tools you are using will explode if you do.